# Searching a column to a match of a given cell

Tags: excel

I have a column that I need to compare against another column.

If the content of my column are in the other column I need to return true.

Here is what I tried but it isn't working, it only seems to work if they are on the exact same line.

```
=OR(EXACT(F2, $B$2:$B$595))
```

F column is the cell I need to search from, B2 thru B595 are what I need to see if F is in.

```
Column B     Column F      True/False
abc           1234          TRUE
bbc           1675          FALSE
1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(F2,$B$2:$B$595,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternate to `MATCH`, you could also use `VLOOKUP` function.

```
Column B  Column F  Column G
abc       1234      =NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(F1,$B$1:$B$595,1,FALSE))) // TRUE
bbc       1675      =NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,$B$1:$B$595,1,FALSE))) // FALSE
1234                =NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(F3,$B$1:$B$595,1,FALSE))) // FALSE
```